# Entire li element is gone

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Customizing a wordpress theme, and having EXTREMELY strange issues.

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/evandentremont.com/

Whenever I try to display a li on the slider, if all of them have background images the entire slider is blank. If one of the li's has no background, it works fine.

No PHP or JS errors at all, and when I use chrome's code inspector, the blocks appear to be there, just invisible. I see the ul, and the li, and the sliding if I mouseover it.

How can I stop this from happening?

```
<li style="
display:block; 
background-image:URL(http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/evandentremont.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/5qqoq5weno_210218126-2.jpg) ; 
height:300px; 
webkit-background-size: cover; 
moz-background-size: cover;
o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; 
">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZ26M/

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demo? That way, once you've fixed the problem, the question still has merit for future visitors.

Comment: Looking at your Fiddle, you didn't read the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) link. Reduce your problem to the minimum code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Trying. The thing is, I can't figure out why I have the problem, let alone minimize to just the problem

Comment: Strip it back to just the gallery. Link only the relevant scripts/css. If the problem doesn't persist with the minimum, then start bringing in other parts, and you'll probably find the part that's breaking stuff. I know it's not easy to do it this way, but it helps us by reducing the code we're looking at and, if done well,   might be enough to show you where the problem is.

Comment: I've added all the relevant-looking resources to this fiddle, but the slider isn't initializing. http://jsfiddle.net/ZhApy/

Answer (score 0):

The `isPreloaded` option of your slider trigger its `complete` event only if your slides contain at least one image (check line 247 of [lofslider](http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/evandentremont.com/wp-content/themes/max-magazine/js/lofslider.js?ver=3.5.1)).

You can set this option to `false` or be sure to have at least one image in your slider.

Or change it!

Comment: Interesting... That explains a lot, though not sure it completely fixes the problem. 

I didn't write the theme, just modifying it. Seems like a strange way to handle things

Comment: A proper fix would be to correct the slider for making it trigger the "complete" event even without any image.